# jsp variable as javascript function parameters

Tags: java, javascript, spring, jsp

I'm having a trouble with using jsp variables as javascript parameters.

The javascript function:

```
function user(name, lastname, nick) {
    return name + " " + lastname + " (" + nick + ")";
}
```

And using it in jsp:

```
<tbody>
<c:forEach var="et" items="${eTestsToAdd}">
    <tr>
        <td><script>document.write(user(${et.author.name}, ${et.author.lastname}, ${et.author.nick}));</script></td>
```

Also it works on another example:

js

```
function parseToDate(dateInMiliseconds) {
    var d = new Date(dateInMiliseconds);
    var string = d.getDay().toString() + "-" + d.getMonth().toString() + "-" + d.getFullYear().toString();
    return string;
}
```

jsp

```
<script>document.write(parseToTime(${uc.startDate.time}));</script>
```

There are two differences, working example is javascript function with one parameter and the parameter is int, and not working one is javasript function with three string parameters. How can I pass those values to have it working? 
No scriptlets please :)

//EDIT

ok, I'll try to clarify it a little more:

I have a table in jsp where some data is to be displayed:

```
<tbody>
    <c:set var="i" value="0" />
    <c:forEach var="uc" items="${userClasses}">
        <c:set var="i" value="${i+1}" />
        <c:url var="usrURL" value="/users/show/${uc.user.nick}" />
        <tr onclick="location.href = '${usrURL}' ">
            <td>${i}</td>
            <td><img class="img-circle img-little" src="<c:url value='/imageView/${uc.user.avatar.id}'/>" />
                <script>document.write(user(${uc.user.name}, ${uc.user.lastname}, ${uc.user.nick}));</script>
            </td>
            <td><script>document.write(parseToTime(${uc.startDate.time}));</script></td>
        </tr>
                                </c:forEach>
                            </tbody>
```

uc.user - is the user entity, I wanted to have it nicely written in the table in pattern -

Name Lastname (userName)

with the javascript I posted here. 
But when I use this function in jsp, tomcat throws me org.apache.jasper.JasperException: An exception occurred processing JSP page  at the line where I call the js function. So obviously, I'm using it wrong in jsp somehow; I'm fresh with javascripts, though. And my question is how to use this javasript function properly here?

Comment: What is the stack trace of the `JasperException`? JavaScript errors dont show up in tomcat and having invalid or JavaScript that doesnt work isnt something that would show up in the Tomcat logs. A JasperException means that your have a JSP error.

Answer (score 1):

I am not certain that this is the solution without knowing what the values for the `eTestsToAdd` collection is, however this would certainly be *one* problem.

Given this code snipplet:

```
document.write(user(${et.author.name}, ${et.author.lastname}, ${et.author.nick}));
```

And the values for the author are `joe`, `shmoe`, `js` respectively this would result in this output

```
document.write(user(joe, shmoe, js));
```

This is invalid javascript, the JS evaluator would look for variables named joe, schome  and js. You need to wrap the output in quotes.

```
document.write(user("${et.author.name}", "${et.author.lastname}", "${et.author.nick}"));
```

Now if someone puts in the name `lovemesome"XXS` for the first name you will also get a javascript error. You will need to sanitize your output variables, you can do that for this case by using the following:

```
${fn:replace(${et.author.name}, '\"', '\\\"'}
```

Comment: @dante02891 what does your javascript console say, do you get an error?

Comment: @dante02891 As i said in my post, noone will be certain of what the problem is until you post what the actual output is of the JSP file. We can guess... but without more information on 1) the error output of the javascript and 2) what exactly are the values that your outputting.  Ideally both would be added to the question but as it is I dont think anyone could awnser and be confident in their solution.