# How to quote/write JSP variable in JavaScript inline attribute code?

Tags: javascript, jsp, attributes

I need to send variables at runtime to a js method for ajax. I am trying with this onclick function but it gives syntax error on click.:

```
<c:set var="abc" value="${myTaglib:getAbc()}" />
<a href="#" onclick="sendAjax(${abc.firstVal}, ${abc.secVal}, ${abc.thirdVal}, ${abc.fourthVal}, ${abc.fifthVal})"> Click Here !!!</a>
```

Some of these values may have spaces and decimals in them. On click, I get this error at the first occurrence of space.:

```
SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list
```

The actual HTML looks like:

```
<a onclick="sendAjax(240265, Workplace Ethics Exam, Company Security Policy, Friends Life, ABF/45RFG, 41444.1830)" href="#">Click Here !</a>
```

What is wrong with this JS call ?

Comment: What is the *actual* HTML returned? That will indicate exactly where the error(s) are - in this case that is trying to write invalid JS literals; probably text values that are not correctly written as string literals. The `${..}` interpolation itself *does not* understand the "JavaScript code" context or how to correctly encode the value.

Comment: Now, *assuming* that the values never contain quotes (either single or double), then `sendAjax('${abc.firstVal}', '${abc.secVal}', ..)` would "fix" that result. Such is still a terrible hack though (as it is manual and will "break randomly" if there are quotes and in some other edge cases); there should be a suitable encoding function - I've created such in C# and I'm sure there is similar for Java/JSP ..

Comment: A related / duplicate question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27496052/jsp-variable-as-javasript-function-parameters?rq=1 (it is not exact because of a different context though!) - with a barely passable / adaptable solution. Ideally there would be a "somewhat elegant" way to do this.

Comment: Note to answers: can someone *please* post a reliable solution, taking the above into account, that will result in guaranteed valid JavaScript for any variable value? Out of several [near] duplicates, all are "manual quote" hacks.

Comment: Well, I can't find much on the subject - google and all. Given my limited "known solution" and my dislike for the hack, I'd write a custom function (http://stackoverflow.com/a/6396886/2864740) and then use that as an appropriate wrapper. It would look like: `sendAjax(${js:lit(abc.firstVal)}, ${js:lit(abc.secVal)}, ..`. Then it's just a matter of writing the "lit" or (to "make a safe literal") function to return a correct value which should be relatively easy.. following the convention that the literal will use single quotes for strings and escape double quotes (used for the attribute quotes).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spaces in your JavaScript code are most likely a syntax error.  If your values have spaces, it's best to treat them as strings.

```
onclick="sendAjax('${abc.firstVal}', '${abc.secVal}', ... '${abc.fifthVal}')">
```

If you want to use them as numbers later, you can use the JavaScript functions `parseInt` and `parseFloat` to turn strings into numbers.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try leaving a space after the last curly brace?

Comment: yes I did.. no effect. I am not sure if I need to use quotes and escape them... But then any of these variables could be string or an integer of a Double with decimal.